# Data type for saving port numbers in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to save all open ports in a row with respect to ip address. Using VARCHAR will limit at some point, or do I have option of limitless VARCHAR() bits?

For example :

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| IP           |                    Open Ports                  |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| 192.168.0.33 | 21, 22, 53, 122, 168, ...., 65535              |
| 192.168.0.1  | 53, 122, 168, 2514, 786, 4548, ...., 65535     |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Which data should be used to declare in

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ports(Ip_address VARCHAR(15), OpenPorts ?????);
```

Comment: How will you use this info? How does these ports values will be used? It can be CSV, JSON array or even additional table. Also MySQL version needed - for example, for current version JSON array is preferred because it can be indexed.

Comment: As mentioned in the link to the duplicate question, create a new table for each individual port. And use an integer column type for the port *number*, not `VARCHAR()`.